# Are there any downsides to having all your DNS records (A, CNAME, etc.) NOT at your hosting company?

Tags: web-hosting, dns, dns-servers

We have a site hosted at Web.com.
Our DNS registrar is Godaddy.com.

Currently Godaddy has the Web.com DNS servers listed. BUT Web.com can't do a `sub.example.com` forward to `example.com/page`.

So I'm considering having ALL the DNS handled at Godaddy (which can handle the above forwarding).

I realize that one downside is that if Web.com changes the IP address that I'll then need to change it manually.

I suspect Web.com would be very unlikely to do that b/c then THEY need to update LOTS of DNS records (for those folks having thair A, CNAME, etc. listed at Web.com)

Any other risks? Is this an odd (or risky) thing to do?

Comment: First things first, DNS does not redirect and **no** you cannot redirect sub.domain.com to domain.com/page. This is not what DNS does. It only ties a domain name to an IP address and other similar mapping for services. Secondly, you are always better off having your DNS with your registrar and not fooling with it. Changing your DNS if you do not know DNS always ends in disaster. So please leave it alone. For your sake. Please.

Comment: I meant that I need Domain Forwarding (at least that's what Godaddy calls it)

Comment: I have not ever looked into the GoDaddy offering. I do not think you can redirect to a sub-directory, however, I could be wrong. If it appears to, it is something to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is neither odd nor risky.  It is actually quite common practice.

The only thing about it is that it can create confusion for people who are inexperienced with the way the system works.  I have a web hosting business and encourage my customers to have everything under one roof for that very reason.

But if you know what you are doing...

Comment: Also, web hosting, dns hosting, and domain registration are often bundled.   You can sometimes get a deal (or a freebie) when you do two or three at the same place.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, you are right, but in this case Godaddy (DNS) is much easier to deal with and provides  Redirects (Subdomain> Domain and Subdomain > domain.com/page).  Web.com does not provide that.